# Time Synchronization Between 2 GPS Controlled Rubidium Clocks

Tags: gps, atomic-clocks

I have 2 GPS Controlled Rubidium Clocks

I need it to be synchronized to one another to the level of a microsecond.
My question is what is the max phase (ns) allowed from the clock's input 1pps, for the 2 clocks to be synchronized to the level of a microsecond?
For example, if 1 clock has a phase drift of -100 ns from the 1pps and the other clock has a  phase drift of +200 ns from the 1pps, will they be synchronized to a level of a microsecond?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This is more of an engineering question rather than a physics question, so I've voted it be closed. You might consider resubmitting it on [Engineering Stack Exchange](//engineering.stackexchange.com).